# Add string by user using form VBA

Tags: excel, vba

first I'd like to say that I'm new to VBA language and probably to some of you this thing seems easy.

In a certain part part of my script I need to put a string (VIN from a car) using a form from Excel. Here is the line where I need to add the text .

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(C, 18).Value = "<EcuDatas VIN_Vehicle=""HERE I NEED TO ADD"">" 
Print #FileNum, Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(C, 18).Value
```

Comment: Are you asking for a function that looks like `GetStringFromCustomVBAUserformThatActsLikeADialog()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use an input box to prompt the user for a string.

Example:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(C, 18).Value = InputBox("VIN Number:", "Enter VIN #")
```